# What's the difference between "=>" operator and {} when calling any methods?

Tags: c#, events, methods, operators

I'm trying to understand the difference between two following expressions. I understand the do the same, but I don't understand the way they do it:

> `private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { method(); }`
>
> `private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => method();`

Which one is the best? Is the second one the equivalent to `inline` modificator of c++?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither is best. They are identical, as long as you're using a C# compiler version that supports the `=>` usage for expression-bodied members (C# 6.0 for methods and read-only properties; C# 7.0 for many other scenarios). Any choice is entirely opinion based. Neither usage relates to `inline` in C++.